# What does it mean to transpose in Matlab fspecial?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, transpose

I am trying to get a vertical edge filter from the Prewitt fspecial function. The documentation in Matlab reads as below:

> `h = fspecial('prewitt')` returns a 3-by-3 filter that emphasizes horizontal edges by approximating a vertical gradient. To emphasize vertical edges, transpose the filter `h'`.

What does it mean by "transpose the filter `h'`"? The documentation does not give any example on how to pass the argument.

Comment: `h` is a matrix. Transpose means to switch rows and columns. You don't need to pass anything to `fspecial`. It's telling you to transpose the returned value,

Comment: Transpose it (i.e., do `h'`). `'` is the transpose operator (for real `h`). The documentation tells you the code, that final `h'` is exactly the code you need, which is why its in a different font, the code font. (yes, not obvious).